# NLog Mail Target is not working

Tags: nlog

I'm using below configuration and expect my error logs go through email, but they don't

```xml
<targets>
  <target name="traceLogger" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Temp\trace.log" layout="${date:format=G} ${level} ${message}"/>
  <target name="warnLogger" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Temp\warning.log" layout="${date:format=G} ${message}"/>
  <target name="infoLogger" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Temp\info.log" layout="${date:format=G} ${message}"/>

  <target name="errorLogger" xsi:type="Mail"
        subject="QC Result Processing Error"
        to="name@domain.com"
        bcc=""
        cc=""
        from="sender@domain.com"
        smtpServer="smtpinfo"/>
 </targets>

 <rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="traceLogger"></logger>
    <logger name="*" levels="Warn" writeTo="warnLogger"></logger>
    <logger name="*" levels="Info" writeTo="infoLogger"></logger>
    <logger name="*" levels="Error" writeTo="errorLogger"></logger>
 </rules>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I enabled nlog exception and found the problem. The issue was the blank bcc and cc. I removed them and the emailing worked fine.

Comment: What does "enabled nlog exception" mean? Is there some config option to log problems that happened within nlog?

Comment: It means enabling logging for NLog itself. By default, NLog doesn't log it's operations. you need to enable it.

Comment: OK, that's what I figured it meant; however, I don't yet know HOW to enable it.

Comment: you can do that by changing the configuration file. I don't remember how I did that, but I think this link will help https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: @RossPresser It is here `  throwExceptions="true"` of the `<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">`

Comment: Doesn't Error and Fatal allow to pass the exception as a parameter beside the message? I tried it and hoped that message and stacktrace would appear in the e-mail body but it doesn't.